# JQuery find an img src

Tags: jquery, parsing

With JQuery I want to be able to get the img src link.

```
   <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td headers="header_0 header_1">&#160;<img
                    src="https://this-link-here.com" width="26"
                    height="24" alt="" border="0" /></td>
```

I have tried

```
   var data = $(data).find("[headers='header_0 header_1']");
```

but this is not getting the link.  Similarly I have tried adding `.text()`, and `.html()` but still no luck.

Can anyone help?  The HTML cannot be changed.

Comment: What is the value of `data` that is being passed to jQuery here: `$(data)`?

Comment: Consider using `data-headers` instead of `headers` as `headers` is not a valid attribute name.

Comment: I cannot change the HTML.  data is the result of $.get

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use either the [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function:

```
var data = $(data).find("[headers='header_0 header_1']").find('img').attr("src");
```

Or the vanilla JS `.src` function, if there is only one with those headers:

```
var data = $(data).find("[headers='header_0 header_1']").find('img').get(0).src;
```

The vanilla JS way is faster, only reason I threw it in.

Comment: vanilla js is fine but what is there are no elements with header `header_0 header_1` accessing `[0].src` will break the code. Also this is not complete vanilla js to make a substantial difference.

Comment: just realized u wanted to find the img under that item, modified my code. now if there are no items with attribute (not id) `header_0 header_1` it wont get to `[0].src` because itll stop searching the DOM tree. and i realize its not pure vanilla js, but the `.attr()` is much slower than its `.href` `.src` and `.id` counterparts, so its a speed improvement nonetheless. please feel free to provide the vanilla JS method of selecting an item using nothing but the headers attribute, because it wasnt worth my time to build that.

Comment: You did not understand see this example breaking.. http://jsfiddle.net/GZDa2/ You cannot access `src or undefined` :)

Comment: @PSL - ah, i see what you mean. updated my answer and your jsFiddle, now they both return `undefined` => http://jsfiddle.net/GZDa2/1/

Comment: Yup that's much like it and +1 for using `find` which is faster that using a selector.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function.

```
var data = $("td[headers='header_0 header_1'] img").attr("src");
```

- P.S - I've changed the selector because something doesn't look right in `var data = $(data) etc.`. You can use a different selector if you wish.

---

## .attr()

> **.attr( attributeName )**
>
> **Returns:** String
>
> **Description:** Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements.

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
var data = $("img", "td[headers='header_0 header_1']").attr("src");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/udeXR/2/